# Python - configuration file

Tags: python-3.x, config, configparser

I have code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from configparser import ConfigParser  
cfg = ConfigParser()
cfg.read('file.cfg')    
plt.plot([1, 10],[2, 2], color_4, ls = "dashed")   
plt.xlim(1,10)
plt.ylim(1,4)
plt.savefig('image.pdf')
```

and I would like control it by configuration file:

```
[a]
color_4 = c = 'silver'
```

What is wrong please? It gives an error:

```
NameError: name 'color_4' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to get the value in this way to get the value of color_4:

`cfg['a']['color_4']`

```
from configparser import ConfigParser  
cfg = ConfigParser()
cfg.read('file.cfg')    
plt.plot([1, 10],[2, 2], cfg['a']['color_4'], ls = "dashed")   
plt.xlim(1,10)
plt.ylim(1,4)
plt.savefig('image.pdf')
```

Ref: [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)